# Multiple scp prompts in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scp

I'm using a shell script that prompts the user for a password multiple times, to execute multiple scp operations. I know there are ways to circumvent password prompts, or save your password in the script. I would like to avoid those options.

Rather, can I add something to the shell script so that it remembers the password the first time it's entered?

Answer (score 0):

What would probably be the better solution is to use private/public keys, but I guess this is not what you're looking for.

Another solution is to use `sshpass` (which you would probably have to install using your package manager). This program allows to enter the password directly in the command line, which is not possible with the `ssh` or `scp` commands.

For instance:

```
echo "Password for host1: "
read -s phost1
sshpass -p "$phost1" scp file.txt user@host1:~
```